# Click on listview item in app widget (remoteviews) not launching activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-pendingintent, remoteview

I'm trying to create my first app widget and I want to be able to start an activity when an item is clicked, but it's not working.
Here is my code in the onUpdate():

```
Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, TareaModificar.class);
toastIntent.putExtra("id", id);
PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_tareas_listview, toastPendingIntent);
```

and the code from my getViewAt():

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(WidgetTareas.id, cursor.getInt(0));
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_tareas, fillInIntent);
```

id is a global string variable in the widget provider.

**EDIT** I'm giving all the code, maybe this way it's easier to help:

AppWidgetProvider code:

```
public class WidgetTareas extends AppWidgetProvider {
private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private DbAdapter dbAdapter;
public static final String id = "1";

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Se actualiza el widget: " +i);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                appWidgetIds[i]);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i],
                remoteViews);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context,
                                         int appWidgetId) {
    dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(context);
    dbAdapter.actualizaQueda(0);
    //which layout to show on widget
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_tareas);

    //RemoteViews Service needed to provide adapter for ListView
    Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetTareasService.class);
    //passing app widget id to that RemoteViews Service
    svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    //setting a unique Uri to the intent
    //don't know its purpose to me right now
    svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(
            svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    //setting adapter to listview of the widget
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.widget_tareas_listview,
            svcIntent);

    Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, TareaModificar.class);
    toastIntent.putExtra("id", id);
    toastIntent.setAction("ACTION_SHOW_TOAST");
    PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_tareas_listview, toastPendingIntent);
    return remoteViews;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Intent received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (intent.getAction()) {
        case "ACTION_SHOW_TOAST":
            //change your activity name
            int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context,
                    TareaModificar.class)
                    .setFlags(
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
            break;
    }
}
```

}

The RemoteViewsFactory code:

```
    @Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        cursor = dbAdapter.getTareasOrdenadoHacer(0);

    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(), R.layout.a);
    Log.d(TAG,"Se carga la factoría");
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    String a = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.COL_A));
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.tarea_widget_aa, dbAdapter.getAA(a));
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.tarea_widget_tt, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.COL_T)));
    String queda = context.getString(R.string.en) +" "+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.COL_Q)) +" "+context.getString(R.string.dias);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.tarea_widget_q, queda);

    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.tarea_widget_pos, position);


    // Next, we set a fill-intent which will be used to fill-in the pending intent template
    // which is set on the collection view in StackWidgetProvider.
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(WidgetTareas.id, cursor.getInt(0));
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_tareas, fillInIntent);
    return remoteView;
}
```

Widget layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/widget_tareas"
android:background="@color/common_action_bar_splitter">
<TextView
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="#E6E6E6"
    android:text="@string/tareas"/>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/widget_tareas_listview"/>
```

Layout a code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:id="@+id/widget_tareas_item">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="99"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/tarea_widget_q"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="pos"
        android:id="@+id/tarea_widget_pos"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/tarea_widget_aa" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="sad"
        android:id="@+id/tarea_widget_tt" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: whats going wrong currently ? please explain

Comment: @JhamanDas when i click an item from the widget nothing happens i want to start the activity TareaModificar

Answer (score 2):

So i finally managed to make it work. What i have done is take the code from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/StackWidget) and change the minimum, so:

In WidgetTareas class, add:

```
public static final String TAREA_MODIFICAR = "TAREAMODIFICAR";
public static final String EXTRA_ITEM = "1";
```

in the method onUpdate():

```
Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetTareas.class);
        toastIntent.setAction(WidgetTareas.TAREA_MODIFICAR);
        toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
        PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_tareas_listview, toastPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
```

the method onReceive:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(TAREA_MODIFICAR)) {
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        int viewIndex = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, 0);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, TareaModificar.class);
        i.putExtra("id",String.valueOf(viewIndex));
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Vista pulsada es: " + viewIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

and finally in the WidgetTareasService class:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(WidgetTareas.EXTRA_ITEM, cursor.getInt(0));
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_tareas_item, fillInIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage the action in the onReceive of your widget provider.

Prepare your intent in getViewAt method:

```
Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, TareaModificar.class);
toastIntent.putExtra("id", id);
toastIntent.setAction("ACTION_SHOW_TOAST");
PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_tareas_listview, toastPendingIntent);
```

And in your onReceive, manage it:

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        switch (intent.getAction()) {

            case "ACTION_SHOW_TOAST":
                  //change your activity name
                  int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
                   context.startActivity(new Intent(context,
                    TareaModificar.class)
                    .setFlags(
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

                break;
        }
   }
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure the 1st piece of code goes to the getViewAt()? Because this method is in the Factory not the provider, maybe you wanted to say in the method onUpdate()? 2. Android studio asks me to import a class for Constants (SyncStateContract) but when I import it, it says that ACTION_SHOW_GCM_NEWS can't be found. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @androidjunior my bad, its part of my code, forgot to delete it.

Comment: Corrected code. Try it. If you want, I can provide a widget provider with listview. The code could be at onUpdate.

Comment: Still doesn't work, i have updated all the code so it may be easier to find what i'm doing wrong. Also i have wrote a Toast when an intent is received but it only shows when the widget is created.